# How to handle very lage input arrays for competitve programming?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve a programmig problem having reference to 0-1 knapsack problem and i'm stuck at size constraint as for large input the capacity of the bag is of the order 10^9.

so, writing something like int arr[no_of_items][1000000001] in C/C++ is always giving segmentation fault.

i have already tried writing my code in other languages like python but it also gets stuck for such a large array. I don't know how to proceed furthur or whether there's any possible way to it.

Please help me to get the correct approach or redirect to some link which may help me out, and is there any blog or site where queries related to competitve programing are reviewed by other coders.

[EDIT] :  Adding the question as suggested by others

```
There is a king with total land of M unit area. He has N chidren and each of them wishes some unit area of his land. Being a father, he cannot deny his children but he either fulfill the wish of his/her child or doesn't give him anything.

Given the total unit area of his land and demands by each child, the problem is to find out which of his children should he choose to give his property so that maximum of his land will be distributed.

Sample input:

15 3
5 8 9

Sample ouput:
0 2

Explaination:

first line is size of total kingdom and number of children he has 
second line contains demand by each child.

Here, he can give away land in following manners:

{} : Gives nothing
{5} : Gives 5  unit area
{8} : Gives 8  unit area
{9} : Gives 9  unit area
{5,8} : Gives 13  unit area
{5,9} : Gives 14  unit area
{8,9} : Gives 17  unit area (Not possible)
{5,8,9} : Gives 22  unit area (Not possible)

Since, out of all possible combinations choosing {5,9} will result in maximum land distribution hence, the king will give his property to 0th and 2nd child.

Constraints:

Maximum land size : 10^9
Maximum no. of child : 10^5
Maximum demand by each child : 1<= demand <=maximum_land_size

Note: The demand by each sucessive children will be greater than previous one.
```

Comment: You need to include the OS and version you are using.

Comment: Please share the problem and what you tried so far.

Comment: @GuyCoder OS :ubuntu 18.04 LTS, C++ version: 7.4.0

Comment: @unlut : The question is simply 0-1 Knapsack problem where  number of items can be 10^5  and capacity of sack can be 10^9. I am trying to use the plain old DP approach storing all the sub-results in 2-D array.

Comment: I guess that the goal of the exercise is to implement an algorithm that does not need such a huge memory

Comment: To be more explicit, you may have a look at the *meet-in-the-middle* algorithm

Comment: For a sanity check, if `int` takes 4 bytes, then a 2D array of size 10^5 * 10^9 takes 400 TB of memory. So no wonder it doesn't work!

Comment: @Damien : Yeah that's what i want to know, if there's any space optimized solution to achieve this. Can you help me with any sample problem that uses meet-in-the-middle approach and have any reference with my question.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on this subject is rather clear, with a section dedicated to the meet-in-the-middle algorithm (but check the corresponding amount of memory before implementing!): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: It's very likely you're using the wrong approach, or that there's a trick to the specific question that allows you to find a cheap solution to the problem. For example, perhaps the size of the items is such that a greedy solution works even though it doesn't in general. Do you have a link to the actual question?

Comment: Clearly the naive approach doesn't work.  And therefore there is something about the problem statement that allows a clever approach to work.  But without the problem statement all we can say is, "Nope, you can't do it that way."  Now what are the missing details in the actual problem?

Comment: Added the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly for your specific case, but in general the strategies here will include things like:

1. only loading part of the array into memory at a time and putting the rest on disk
2. having a function that can generate the element at index 0 <= k < n rather than storing all n items
3. using message-passing parallelism (GPGPU, MPI, etc.) to divide the data among processors
4. related to (2), having a way of solving the problem without storing the data at all

You can probably configure compiler settings to make using that much heap or stack possible (e.g., telling the compiler you can use lots of stack, compiling for x64, etc.) but these are not generalizable solutions in that they might solve the 10^9 case but will not solve the 10^12 or 10^15 cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/
you should rewrite it in a way that uses a lot less memory.

Specifically you can see that for any value of `i` you only care about `K[i][...]` and `K[i-1][...]`; so no need to remember all the other values, i.e. instead of `n*W` elements you need `2*W` elements.

Comment: The solution you are talking about that's fine but my actual issue is i'm not able to define an array of size W i.e, 10^9.

2*10^9 is a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use dictionary or in c++ you can use unordered_map([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)).

In Python, you can use dictionary with the key as a tuple. So instead of checking previous value as DP[i][w], you can check it as DP[(i,w)].

sample code

```
from collections import defaultdict

dp = defaultdict(lambda : -1)

#access it as dp[(i,w)],  if (i,w) is not a key then it will return -1
```

It has constant average time complexity for accessing the value  for a key

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i'll try this but will this suffice for my space issue.